# Does ScyllaDB Support Latest Version of Metrics?

Tags: maven, cassandra, nosql, datastax-java-driver, scylla

When I launch `ScyllaDB` for the first time:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints("xx.xxx.xx.xxx").build();
Session session = cluster.connect("my_scylladb_cluster");

System.out.println(session.isClosed());
```

I get the following error:

```
===== Using optimized driver!!! =====
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/JmxReporter
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Metrics.<init>(Metrics.java:156)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1773)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:228)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:401)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:352)
    at scylladbX.ScyllaDBXMain.main(ScyllaDBMain.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codahale.metrics.JmxReporter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

In my `Maven POM` file I'm using the latest version of `Metrics`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-graphite -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-graphite</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

I noticed that if I downgrade to a much earlier version of `Metrics`, the problem goes away:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codahale.metrics/metrics-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codahale.metrics/metrics-graphite -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-graphite</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Does `ScyllaDB` not support the latest version of `Metrics`? What is the latest version supported?

Thanks

Comment: what version of java driver are you using?

Comment: @AlexOtt `java -version` shows `java version "1.8.0_191"`

Comment: No. Datastax Java driver that you call ScyllaDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataStax Java Driver documentation [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/metrics/) has a section about the problem you saw:

> While the driver depends on Metrics 3.2.x, it also works with Metrics 4, with some caveats.
> In Metrics 4, JMX reporting was moved to a separate module, metrics-jmx. Because of this you are likely to encounter the following exception at runtime when initializing a Cluster:
>
> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/JmxReporter
>    at com.datastax.driver.core.Metrics.<init>(Metrics.java:103)
>    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1402)
>    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:159)
>    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:330)
>    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:305)
>    at com.datastax.durationtest.core.DurationTest.createSessions(DurationTest.java:360)
>        ....
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codahale.metrics.JmxReporter
>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
>    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
>    ... 8 more
> ```

That document also has suggestions what to do in this case.

In any case, this problem has nothing to do with Scylla (the backend server you want to connect to) - and is just a problem with the Java client ("driver") you are using.